# wordpress wp_schedule_event without traffic

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a question, I write an plugin with function that will send mail to customers after x days. I created the function.
Now, I need that the function will run only once a day.
Here is the code:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
}

function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
}
```

From this link: http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-cron-jobs-in-wordpress

But the schedule works only when there is traffic on the site, which means that if I closed the browser, after one hour the function doesn't run and the email doesn't sent.

It's possible to run cron job with Wordpress?

Thanks!

Comment: Is guess you are looking for [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cronjob-scheduler/)

Comment: In my experience, the only way to ensure this works properly is to additionally set up an *actual crontab job* on the server.  This article covers it well: https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/

Comment: Best to insure using third party site like [cron-job](https://cron-job.org/en/)